# I want to show loading bar on Specific index in GridView/List View

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dart-pub

[image]

The issue is that It is showing on all except for only one index

Comment: Can you include what you’ve tried so far?

Comment: Just added the Progress bar in the Girdview using stack and now I want to show the loading bar on a specific index.

Comment: Can you include your gridView?

Answer (score 1):

While showing `CircularProgressIndicator` you can use condition, like

```dart
 Widget item({
    required bool showProgressBar,
  }) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        /// item widgets
        if (showProgressBar) const CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ],
    );
  }
```

And On `GridView`'s

```dart
child: GridView.count(
  crossAxisCount: 2,
  children: List.generate(
    totalItemLength,
    (index) => item(showProgressBar: sepecifiqIndex == index),
  ),
),
```